Recoding a series of variables with names of the form NAMEx where x is a numeric series
I have a series of variables of the form NAMEx to which I want to apply the same recoding scheme. (In stata I would do this using "recode NAME* (recode specifications)"
My inclination was to use a for loop with a list of column names, but that does not seem to be the accepted approach in R (and produces errors). I also tried using the recode statement from package car but that produced a different error.
It appers that the way to do this in R involves using the lapply() function and I tried this:
v1 <- c(1,5,7,9)
v2 <- c(2,7,9,6)
v3 <- c(8,3,4,7)

df <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3)
df
namelist=c("df$v1","df$v2","df$v3")
namelist
myrecode <- function(x) {
        case_when(x==7 ~ 77,
                  x==9 ~ 99,
                 .default ~ x)}
lapply(namelist,myrecode,data=df)

Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
unused argument (data = list(c(1, 5, 7, 9), c(2, 7, 9, 6), c(8, 3, 4, 7)))
Note that I have some places where I need to replace values of one variable (x) conditional on the value of a second variable (y), and I would want to be able to do that with a function that would look like:
myrecode <- function(x,y) {x[y==27] = 2
Is there anything special I need to know here?

It is best practice to provide your expected output when posting on SO. This would help clarify your post. I am not clear what you are trying to accomplish in your "Note that I have some places..."

library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(across(v1:v3, \(x) case_match(x, 7 ~ 77, 9 ~ 99, .default = x)))
#   v1 v2 v3
# 1  1  2  8
# 2  5 77  3
# 3 77 99  4
# 4 99  6 77

